# Post request through ajax doesn't appear to be working properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, post

I have form that makes a request via post managed by ajax. However, it does not appear to be working at all. I know the php file works as I've tried it without using ajax in the middle.

This is my ajax request:

```
function checkOut(params) {
    var urlString = params;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
       //Setup for post submission  
       xmlhttp.open("POST","mockcheckout.php",true);
       xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
       xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

       xmlhttp.send(urlString); 

    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I recommend you to use jQuery and dump that ActiveX code.

Comment: What do you mean by "*does not seem to be working*"? Please describe any errors (or does your error console log some?)

Comment: I agree. But before I do that, I'd like to get a firmer grasp of jquery - I know it's easier. Or, if you can give me an example of how to translate the above ajax into jquery, I can work with that.

Comment: I should've been clearer. Nothing happens. It just doesn't work.

Comment: You do not need to set the `content-length` header (might even not be allowed to?), this is done automatically.

Comment: I've removed it, and it still doesn't function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a problem with code blocks. `.open`, `.send` should be outside of `onreadystatechange` handler scope.

```
function checkOut(params) {
    var urlString = params;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    //Setup for post submission  
    xmlhttp.open("POST","mockcheckout.php",true);  
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
    xmlhttp.send(urlString);     
}
```